# Calculating Silhouette score for KMeans (1.5 million rows)

Tags: python, runtime, k-means

I'm trying to calculate the silhouette score in order to determine the optimal number of clusters for a KMeans algorithm. The thing is, I have over 1.5 million rows (only 5 columns though) and it doesn't seem to be working. I've let it run for over 2 hours.

I'm trying the following chunk of code:

```
K_list = range(2, 10)
SC = []

for k in K_list:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, n_init = 10, random_state=1337) 
    kmeans.fit(X_train)
    y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(X_train)
    SC.append(silhouette_score(X_train ,y_kmeans))
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
kmeans_per_k = [KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=42).fit(X_train) for k in range(2, 7)]
silhouette_scores = [silhouette_score(X_train, model.labels_) for model in kmeans_per_k[1:]]
```

Is there something wrong with the code?